# how do I Separating a List<Object> in razor View

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor

I am passing a List with two different types to my view from the controller Example1 and Example2. I am foreaching through the List to display its contents. I can see the two list in the Object List, [0]-5 Entries and [1]-4 Entries. 1st entry is my Example1Deatil and Second is my Example2Detail.

What i am trying to do is have Example1 to be built out on one table and Example2 on another by checking the type. I know they are of Type Object so trying to figure out how to get their original type. so the type checks work correctly.

Edit: What i am passing in is two List one of type Example1Deatil and Example2Detail. They are both in the List(object) that was passed in.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    //Edit: This is how I got my List<Object> that contained my two
    // List of List<Example1> and List<Example2> to work.

   foreach(var result in item  as IEnumerable<object>
     //  This was the problem  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     // The list in the list where just type object and not a List of Objects.
     // and now everything is working. Thank you to those who helped.

    if (result is Models.Example1Models.Example1Detail)
    {
        <table>
             //Example1 contents are different than Example2's contents.
        </table>
    }


    if (result is Models.Example2Models.Example1Detail)
    {
        <table>
             //Example2 Contents
        </table>
    }
```

Comment: Is that code not working?

Comment: No, When i run with the pattern matching it still skips over the if statement

Comment: that means type of object is different than what you are using in if condition. Kindly check type of result and use pattern matching to draw the table

Comment: Figured it out. What was happening is my model is List<Object> with 2 list one Example1  and Example2 had to use two foreach loops. the 1st foreach was foreach list and was comparing the list to the model I was looking for. The second foreach went into the actual list.

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        IList<object> list = new List<object>();
        list.Add(1);
        list.Add("one");

        return View(list);
    }
```

View

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>

@foreach (var result in Model)
{

    if (result is int)
    {
        <div>int</div>
    }

    if (result is string)
    {
        <div>string</div>
    }

}
```